# How to add photos to employer icon on Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

How may one add photos to employer field on Facebook page?

Answer (score 2):

That icon is affected by the photo uploaded to the relevant Facebook page that it links to. To change that, you need to have permission to change the photo of that Facebook page photo as well.